# Pandas on Spark 3.2 -NLP.pipe - pd.Series.__iter__() is not implemented

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas, pyspark-pandas

I'm currently trying to migrate some processes from python to (pandas on) spark to measure performance, everything went good until this point:

df_info is of type pyspark.pandas

nlp is defined as:
`nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm', disable=["tagger", "parser"])`

```
def lemmatize_pipe(doc):
    lemma_list = [str(tok.lemma_).lower() for tok in doc] 
    return lemma_list

def preprocess_pipe(texts):
    preproc_pipe = []
    for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=20):
        preproc_pipe.append(lemmatize_pipe(doc))
    return preproc_pipe

df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'])
```

I got this error on for doc on *nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=20):*

> PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.

Referenced here:

```
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-eb93782f-db7f-4f94-97bf-409a980a51f7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/language.py in pipe(self, texts, as_tuples, batch_size, disable, component_cfg, n_process)
   1570         else:
   1571             # if n_process == 1, no processes are forked.
-> 1572             docs = (self._ensure_doc(text) for text in texts)
   1573             for pipe in pipes:
```

Any idea of how can I solve this?

----EDIT----
Converting to numpy:

`df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'].to_numpy())`

changes the error to:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1319548240307049> in <module>
      9     return preproc_pipe
     10 
---> 11 df_info['text'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'].to_numpy())


/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    192             start = time.perf_counter()
    193             try:
--> 194                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    195                 logger.log_success(
    196                     class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
  11812             ):
  11813                 psdf = self.reset_index()
> 11814                 psdf[key] = ps.DataFrame(value)
  11815                 psdf = psdf.set_index(psdf.columns[: self._internal.index_level])
  11816                 psdf.index.names = self.index.names

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    187         if hasattr(_local, "logging") and _local.logging:
    188             # no need to log since this should be internal call.
--> 189             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    190         _local.logging = True
    191         try:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
  11799                         yield (psdf._psser_for(this_label), this_label)
  11800 
> 11801             psdf = align_diff_frames(assign_columns, self, value, fillna=False, how="left")
  11802         elif isinstance(value, list):
  11803             if len(self) != len(value):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/utils.py in align_diff_frames(resolve_func, this, that, fillna, how, preserve_order_column)
    421     # it adds new columns for example.
    422     if len(this_columns_to_apply) > 0 or len(that_columns_to_apply) > 0:
--> 423         psser_set, column_labels_set = zip(
    424             *resolve_func(combined, this_columns_to_apply, that_columns_to_apply)
    425         )

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/frame.py in assign_columns(psdf, this_column_labels, that_column_labels)
  11789                 psdf: DataFrame, this_column_labels: List[Label], that_column_labels: List[Label]
  11790             ) -> Iterator[Tuple["Series", Label]]:
> 11791                 assert len(key) == len(that_column_labels)
  11792                 # Note that here intentionally uses `zip_longest` that combine
  11793                 # that_columns.
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your `df_info`? What is `nlp` you imported? Also, is `lemmatize_pipe` a function defined by you?

Comment: Added hoy NLP is defined, the error I have is on the for loop line, not in the lemmatize thas is only this line:
```lemma_list = [str(tok.lemma_).lower() for tok in doc] ```
The field text on df_info is a short text I cannot share, sorry, but a string of fewer than 140 chars approx.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the additional info. I didn't get one thing: what is exactly `lemmatize_pipe`? In your comment above you described `lemma_list`, not `lemmatize_pipe`

Comment: Added lemmatize_pibe definition

Answer (score 0):

It seems to fundamentally be a type error that only gets caught when trying to iterate over `texts` in `nlp.pipe()` ([line 1572 of `spacy/language.py`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/v3.2.3/spacy/language.py#L1572) as you cited).

`texts` must be an [iterable (list, tuple, anything implementing `__iter__`) of strings](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe). `df_info['text']` instead appears to be a `pd.Series`.

You may need to use [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas-series-values), `pd.Series.array`, or make a call to `pd.Series.to_numpy()` as the error you shared suggests.

```
df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'])  # original
# df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'].values)
# df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'].array)
# df_info['text_2'] = preprocess_pipe(df_info['text'].to_numpy())
```

If you can share a sample of `df_info` as [Ric S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7465462/ric-s) asked in the comments, you may get stronger answers as well.

Comment: To be clear, with import pandas as pd works perfectly. the issue is when I use pandas on spark as. import pyspark.pandas as ps. Will try this, thanks

Comment: Tried that, thanks, but now I have a new error, added it to the quesstion, thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro I don't as much about the subtle differences between pyspark.pandas and pandas.. You are saying `df_info['text'].to_numpy()` works when doing `import pandas as pd` but not when doing `import pyspark.pandas as ps`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure is a pyspark.pandas problem and spacy, but don't know how to get around it. Thanks!